# R Shiny: Calling modules from inside another Shiny app confines them to only half my screen

Tags: r, shiny

I've encapsulated several small Shiny apps into modules. When calling these modules individually from the command line they display as expected, filling the entire page. I want to create an app where a user can select different modules from a menu. I've been trying to do this with navbarPage and tabPanel, but the modules always display at half the height of my screen.

I've tried wrapping various elements in divs/boxes and changing their height, but it only changes the height of the container around my modules, not the modules themselves. I'm pretty new to Shiny, and I think I must be misunderstanding something about the relationship between modules and the apps that call them.

Reproducible example:

```
WGStableUI <- function(id){ fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput(NS(id,"dynamic"))
)
}

WGStableServer <- function(id){ 
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
  #WGS_tbl <- tbl(connection,"WGS") %>% as_tibble()
  #output$dynamic <- renderDataTable(WGS_tbl, options = list(pageLength = 5))
  output$dynamic <- renderDataTable(mtcars, options = list(pageLength = 100))
})}

WGStableApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    WGStableUI("displayWGStable")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    WGStableServer("displayWGStable")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}
```

```
library(shiny)
source("./WGS_table_module.R")
ui <- navbarPage("title",
  tabPanel("page1"),
  tabPanel("page2",WGStableApp())
)
server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Edit: still trying to figure this one out, I have realized that just calling a module from inside another app is causing an issue, the tabPanels have no effect. There are scroll bars, but I can't change the size of the display window. Same thing happens just doing:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- WGStableApp()


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Erik, I am not experiencing the same issue with your example. The app fills the entire page for me.

Comment: I'm completely lost on this one. If I call the module by itself, it fills the whole page. If I take the code out of the module, put it in a new app, but enclose the dataTableOutput in a tabPanel, it fills the whole page. If I call the module from inside another app, it's confined to half the page.

One thing I have just realized is it has nothing to do with the tabPanels, calling the module from inside any other app makes it half height, regardless of what's around it. I just tried it with only ui <- WGStableApp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out why this was happening, but I did find a solution. Instead of calling the UI and server modules together as I did above, I created another module, which called each UI and server element separately, and then I called that new module from an app.

Example:

```
menu_ui <- function(id) {
  
  navbarPage("Menu",
    tabPanel("WGS Epi Table",WGStableUI(NS(id, "infotable")))
  )
  
}

menu_server <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    WGStableServer("infotable")
    
  })
  
}

demo_menu <- function() {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(menu_ui("demomenu"))
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    menu_server("demomenu")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  
}
```